# Can't call the BroadcastReceiver from an Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am new to android ,here I have two activities and a BroadcastReceiver .

I am trying to call the BroadcastReceiver from first activity through the second activity .

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aviz.www.reminder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Classes.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Classes.AlarmActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Classes.CreateAlarm"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
<activity android:name=".Activity_Classes.WakeUpScreen"></activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

WakeUpScreen.java

```
 mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alarmActivity.stopAlarm(getBaseContext());
            }
        });
```

I am trying to stop the alarm from the wakeupscreen for that I called the method in AlarmActivity to cancel the current pendingIntent

AlarmActivity.java

```
   public void stopAlarm(Context context){
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
      intent.setAction("ALARM_OFF");
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,mAlarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
  }
```

From this method (intent ) I want to call the BroadcastReceiver  for stopping (current pendingIntent) the alarm.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarmtone);

        String alarmAction = intent.getAction();
        if (alarmAction.equals("ALARM_ON")) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, WakeUpScreen.class);
            context.startActivity(intent1);

            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(100, 100);
            player.start();

        } else if (alarmAction.equals("ALARM_OFF")) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging the app stopAlarm(Context context) method called from the WakeUpScreen.java and the debugger also crossed all the lines in stopalarm() method but the AlarmReceiver is not get called .

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: ALARM_ON  and ALARM_OFF are actions or Extras for your intent?

Comment: That are actions @Man

Comment: Then how are you doing intent.putExtra("Action","ALARM_OFF"), It's just extra.Please can you post your receiver section from Manifest And Receiver's onReceive method.?

Comment: I will update all my code within 5 minutes @Man

Comment: I have updated all my code please check it and help me to solve the issue please @Man

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK AlarmManager.cancel is only used to cancel exisiting PendingIntent task.
And It does not excute the pending intent while cancelling.

In your case after cancelling the Alarm you'll have to manually send broadcast with your "ALARM OFF" extra intent.

```
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
 intentFilter.addAction("ALARM_ON");
 intentFilter.addAction("ALARM_OFF");
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new AlarmReceiver(), 
 intentFilter);
 mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alarmActivity.stopAlarm(getBaseContext());

                Intent intent = new Intent("ALARM_OFF");
                intent.setClass(WakeUpScreen.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(WakeUpScreen.this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please edit my code and  make it work ,"In your case after cancelling the Alarm you'll have to manually send broadcast with your "ALARM OFF" extra intent." I could not understand these @Man

Comment: looking for your response @Man

Comment: It's fine. you could've defined your actions ALARM_ON, ALARM_OFF in Manifest.But While Registering I took care of that.

Comment: did you try to debug?Is it going in Receiver?

Comment: Not going to receiver but it crossed all the lines inside the onClick of wakeupscreen @Man

Comment: What about IntentFilter lines? You really updated it correctly?

Comment: Just copy pasted it bro not even changed a single . here @ Man

Comment: try intent.setClass(WakeUpScreen.this, AlarmReceiver.class); from updated answer.